# How to reset the value of a field automtically in mongoDB after certain period of time?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a `users` collection. Each collection has a field called `pin` which happens to be the security pin,required for monetary operations. The default value of the pin is set to `null` while declaring the schema using mongoose.js. When the user generates his pin from the app, the 'pin' field holds a 6-digit integer value. **My goal is to automatically reset this value to 'null' after (say) 30sec. How can this be acheived in mongoDB/mongoose ?**

This is what my schema looks like :

```
 const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                /**
                    other 
                    fields
                    and 
                    vaidations 
                **/
              pin : {type:Number,default:null}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```